# How to create IReliableDictionary inside Actor?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

There is the following code snippet provided [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-quick-start/) for creating `IReliableDictionary` inside of `StatefulService` subclass:

```
var myDictionary = await this.StateManager.
    GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, long>>("myDictionary");
```

My question is about how to write similar code but for `Actor`. There is only following declaration inside of `IActorStateManager` which supports T Value as a 2-nd parameter:

```
Task<T> GetOrAddStateAsync<T>(string stateName, T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

The issue is I can't find `IReliableDictionary` implementations available. How the correct snippet should looks like?

Comment: The first snippet is for reliable service, the second one is the method of reliable actor. The state managers are of different type then...

Comment: Good point, I've updated a post with more `Actor` related context. Actually my question is about how to add `ReliableDictionary` to Actor's StateManager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the way an actor works (turn based access model, state replication/persistence, etc.) it doesn't really make sense to be using an IReliableDictionary in the actor state - you can use a normal Dictionary and you will get all the benefits you'd get from a stateful service using a reliable collection.

Comment: What if you need to share a table of values across multiple actors? -- (i.e. a lookup table, etc. which should be stored globally to the service and not a specific actor) -- How then do you get a handle to that Reliable Dictionary from the stateful service that is hosting your actors?

Comment: When I hold a large collection of objects and actor happens to update one element in it, this would result in serialising (and sending over the wire) the whole collection then, would it? 
As I understand reliable collections in stateful services in this scenario would only serialise/replicate just the updated element. Is this a wrong assumption?